# Phase correction of a received signal

Tags: fft, matlab, filters, phase, bandpass

How is it possible to correct the possible phase distortion of a typical signal which has been received by an antenna and passed through different analog elements including an amplifier and a band pass filter?

From band pass filter data sheet, I do have the group delay information per frequency in Nano second.
For the antenna, I have some information about the phase response from the simulation.
I wonder if and how the amplifier would affect the phase part of the signal.

I have measured the magnitude frequency response of the elements and corrected the received signal on in terms of amplitude.
For that, and after taking the FFT of the signal and separating the magnitude part, I made the corrections and then re-created the signal and used an inverse Fourier function to take back the signal to time-domain.
But I intend to also correct the possible phase distortion.
I do the analyses in MATALB.

Thanks.

Comment: You need these two concepts: "channel equalizer" and "all-pass filter".